# 64 bit enum in C++?

Tags: c++, enums, 64-bit

Is there a way to have a 64 bit enum in C++?  Whilst refactoring some code I came across bunch of #defines which would be better as an enum, but being greater than 32 bit causes the compiler to error.

For some reason I thought the following might work:

```
enum MY_ENUM : unsigned __int64  
{  
    LARGE_VALUE = 0x1000000000000000,  
};
```

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer `unsigned __int64` over `uint64_t`? I think `uint64_t` is defined for almost every relevant platform, but `unsigned __int64` sounds like a platform (hardware, compiler or even library) specific definition.

Comment: @Johan ```__int64``` is a Microsoft-C++ specific alias for ```long long```.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think that's possible with C++98. The underlying representation of enums is up to the compiler. In that case, you are better off using:

```
const __int64 LARGE_VALUE = 0x1000000000000000L;
```

As of C++11, it is possible to use enum classes to specify the base type of the enum:

```
enum class MY_ENUM : unsigned __int64 {
    LARGE_VALUE = 0x1000000000000000ULL
};
```

In addition enum classes introduce a new name scope. So instead of referring to `LARGE_VALUE`, you would reference `MY_ENUM::LARGE_VALUE`.

Comment: This is what I resorted to in the end, but I was curious as to whether 64 bit enums are possible, even with a compiler specific extension.

Comment: MSVC 8 (2005) already supports the underlying type as non-standard extension.

Answer (score 18):

C++11 supports this, using this syntax:

```
enum class Enum2 : __int64 {Val1, Val2, val3};
```

Comment: I was close then. I must of read about the `: type` syntax somewhere.

Comment: note that `class` is still optional. If you want old style enum, but with a custom type, you can also `enum moo : long long {...}`

Answer (score 8):

The current draft of so called [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x), it is [n3092](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf) says in **7.2 Enumeration declarations**, paragraph 6:

> It is implementation-defined which
>   integral type is used as the
>   underlying type except that the
>   underlying type shall not be larger
>   than int unless the value of an
>   enumerator cannot fit in an int or
>   unsigned int.

The same paragraph also says:

> If no integral type can represent all
>   the enumerator values, the enumeration
>   is ill-formed.

My interpretation of the part  **unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an int or unsigned int** is that it's perfectly valid and safe to initialise enumerator with 64-bit integer value as long as there is 64-bit integer type provided in a particular C++ implementation.

For example:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    Undefined = 0xffffffffffffffffULL
};
```

Comment: If you don't want count out your f's you can just do `Undefined = ~0x0ULL`

Answer (score 4):

The answers refering to `__int64` miss the problem. The enum *is* valid in all C++ compilers that have a true 64 bit integral type, i.e. any C++11 compiler, or C++03 compilers with appropriate extensions. Extensions to C++03 like `__int64` work differently across compilers, including its suitability as a base type for enums.

Answer (score 2):

If the compiler doesn't support 64 bit enums by compilation flags or any other means I think there is no solution to this one.

You could create something like in your sample something like:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
const uint64 LARGE_VALUE = 0x1000000000000000;
};
```

and using it just like an enum using

```
MyNamespace::LARGE_VALUE
```

or

```
using MyNamespace;
....
val = LARGE_VALUE;
```

Comment: And loose type safety, though.

Comment: The speed of our conversation reminds me of correspondence chess :D

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working in C++, another alternative might be

```
const __int64 LARVE_VALUE = ...
```

This can be specified in an H file.

Comment: I cheated 9 chars with first try.

Answer (score 1):

your snipplet of code is not c++ standard:

> enum MY_ENUM : unsigned __int64

does not make sense.

use const __int64 instead, as Torlack suggests

Comment: he has prolly seen it in another curly brace language (e.g. C# supports it) or in the upcoming C++ standard, where this will be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Enum type is normally determined by the data type of the first enum initializer. If the value should exceed the range for that integral datatype then c++ compiler will make sure it fits in by using a larger integral data type.If compiler finds that it does not belong to any of the integral data type then compiler will throw error.
Ref: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf

Edit: However this is purely depended on machine architecture

Answer (score 0):

An enum in C++ can be any integral type. You can, for example, have an enum of chars. IE:

```
enum MY_ENUM
{
   CHAR_VALUE = 'c',
};
```

I would *assume* this includes __int64. Try just

```
enum MY_ENUM
{
   LARGE_VALUE = 0x1000000000000000,
};
```

According to my commenter, sixlettervariables, in C the base type will be an int always, while in C++ the base type is whatever is large enough to fit the largest included value. So both enums above should work.

Comment: @Doug T.: while ANSI C dictates that enumerations are the size of the 'int' data type, ISO C++ dictates that enumerations are of the size at least as large as required to represent all values.

Answer (score 0):

In MSVC++ you can do this:

enum MYLONGLONGENUM:__int64 { BIG_KEY=0x3034303232303330, ... };