# Enum with 64 bit underlying integer

Tags: c++, gcc, enums

I'm using gcc, which implements enums as 32 bit integers on the architecture I have (don't know in general).  If I try to assign an enum value too large, I get

`warning: integer overflow in expression`

Is there a way to make gcc use 64 bit integers as the underlying integer type?  A gcc specific way is fine, although if there's a portable way, that's even better.

** Edit **
This is a related post: [64 bit enum in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76624/64-bit-enum-in-c)

Unlike that question, I'm also interested in gnu extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me with `-std=c++0x`, but not with `-std=c++98` though

```
enum EnumFoo {
    FooSomething = 0x123456789ULL
};
```

I tested this with

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
```

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using?  This doesn't seem to work for 4.3.4, I still get a 32bit enum.

Comment: @pythonic metaphor: Updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: `ULL` should tell your compiler to use C99's `unsigned long long` type, which has a minimum width of 64 bits (and is defined to be exactly 64 bits wide on all implementations I'm aware of.) However, if your compiler doesn't support `long long` (e.g. if you're in GCC and using *strict* C++98, which is what is meant by `-std=c++98`), `ULL` will either be seen as an error, or the extra `L` will be ignored and you'll get an `unsigned long` (which is often 32 bits wide.) I don't recall exactly which behaviour is standards-conformant offhand, but if it's giving you 32 bits, I suspect the latter.

Answer (score 0):

one option: create a template class with a `static const` member of a specific type.

for example `std::tr1::integral_constant`, declared in c++/tr1/type_traits in the GNU distribution (at least, the one i'm using).

for an enum value: your declaration could matter (e.g., use `U`, `L` as appropriate)