# Warning : left shift count >= width of type

Tags: c, enums, 64-bit

I have declared this enum in my header file:

```
enum wildcard {
  ....
  ....
  NW_SRC  = 0x111UL << 40,
  ....
};
```

When I compile it I get the following warning:

```
warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
```

I think this is because enum type is treated as an `int` by the compiler. How to I resolve this?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76624/64-bit-enum-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UL` on your platform is probably 32 bit. You may need to use `ULL` instead:

```
enum wildcard {
    ....
    ....
    NW_SRC  = 0x111ULL << 40,
    ....
};
```

This will fix the warning, but the result of the expression may not necessarily fit in an `enum` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/366026/335858) for details and references to the relevant standard documents).

Answer (score 3):

You have two different problems, first the operation and then the declaration of the constant.

For the operation you could use the macro that is provided in `inttypes.h`

```
UINT64_C(0x111) << 40
```

to have a constant of the appropriate width.

But enumeration constants are `int` by definition of the standard, so this will not help you to define you an enumeration constant that is large enough to hold the value if on your platform `int` is only 32 bit wide (which is very likely).

Comment: In C++ an enum is represented by an integral type large enough to hold all the enumerated values, meaning that it should be represented by long long in this case. Does the C standard really not make the same guarantee?

Comment: @JackAidley: C 2011 6.7.2.2 2: “The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer constant expression that has a value representable as an int.” C 2011 6.7.2.2 3: “The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int…”

Comment: @Eric: thank you. Funny how these little differences in C and C++ can catch you out.

Comment: @JackAidley, yes this is actually a nasty difference, since this is concerning type constants and interface definitions.

Answer (score 2):

`UL` is unsigned long, but long on the majority of compilers is 32-bit. You want `ULL` for unsigned long long.

**But** as correctly pointed out by Jens Gustedt in their answer, in C an enum cannot hold values larger than an int anyway so this will not help. C++, in contrast, does allow enums to be represented by larger integral types.